Suction pipe freezing when blower is on low speed, and runs fine when blower turned to high speed!
I have 12000BTU unit running on R22, and I'm facing a strange issue with my split AC.
When I run it with the indoor blower on low speed, the outdoor starts freezing on the suction pipe. But as soon as I turn the indoor blower on high speed the freezing goes away immediately .
I cleaned everything, indoor and outdoor. As far as I can see there is no airflow restrictions on the unit.
I measure the current of the compressor, and it runs on 5.2A. On the outdoor unit the plate says running current is 6A. Not sure if that's fine.
Also, I measured the suction pressure and it's around 60psi.
Any help on troubleshooting the problem, please.

Make/model #???

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  It's a generic chinese imported in my country, it's called V.5 no specific model tho. The compressor model is  PH225X2C-4FT

what suction ? Fresh air suction ?

The higher fan speed is putting more heat into the refrigerant.
With the lower fan speed, there's less heat in the refrigerant, and your system has hit a state where that causes freeze-up, as the refrigerant is still cold (or too cool) when it hits the outside pipe.
With an old system (R22 is a sure sign) the compressor runs the same speed whatever the fan speed, unlike a newer variable-speed inverter-drive compressor that can slow both fan and compressor down, so the cooling is running full speed regardless of the fan setting.
My general understanding is that the typical reason for that to change from when it didn't do that is loss of refrigerant (a leak) but I don't play refrigeration tech myself. You might have records of what the pressure used to be or is supposed to be.

It's still cool weather now while I'm testing it, in room it's around 25c  and probably 21c-23c outside. Could that have anything to do with it?

Possibly the unit is (sightly) undercharged with R-22 for operation at low fan speed under your conditions, but is it worth it to go to the trouble and expense of adding R-22? This would raise the high side pressure especially when operating at high fan speed. How old is the unit?

According to my old R-22 gauge 60 psi corresponds to 1.4 C (34.5 F)  so the suction line at the condensing unit  would be close to freezing. The real problem of course is if the condensed water on the evaporator coil is freezing. Have you noticed any air flow restriction when the air handler fan is on the low setting? Personally I would just use the unit on high fan setting, but I am not knoweldgeable on the plusses and minuses of these units when op at low evaporator temperature. IIRC the ideal low side pressure was 68 -70 psi for a ~40 - 42 F (~ 5 C) evaporator coil internal temperature .
